# privileged queries in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.3

There are 2 users in DB(PostgreSQL 9.3).
1) The X user do a lot of SELECT/INSERT queries.
2) The Y user do a query which need "ACCESS EXCLUSIVE" lock.

Is there a way to grand the Y user a privilege so the queries from Y user will
1) stop the queries of X users.
2) finish the query of Y user
3) restart the queries of X user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. PostgreSQL doesn't currently support aborting conflicting transactions on lock requests, though it'd be a nice-to-have. You *can* have a periodic task query `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks` looking for queries waiting on an `AccessExclusiveLock` and `pg_terminate_backend` any conflicting workers, but it's a bit heavy handed.

Nor can PostgreSQL re-run aborted queries, the application is expected to do that its self. Consider that the query might be the fourth in a transaction; it'd be completely wrong for Pg to just re-run the last query in the transaction. It must abort the whole transaction. And it doesn't know if it's even correct to re-run it. So the *application* must take care of this.